# Using xsl to figure out if one specific tag is followed by another specific tag

Tags: xslt

I've got code that check to see that head1 isn't empty and writes to an error log:

```
<xsl:template match="w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val='head1']">
    <xsl:variable name="elementValue">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="title.text.only" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$elementValue = ''">
            <xsl:message>ERROR: Encountered an head 1 paragraph with no text content.</xsl:message>
            <xsl:call-template name="revealDocPosition"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="sectionTitle" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

But I also want code that check to see if the the tag that follows head1 is the body tag and if not, give me an error. I don't care about the content of the body tag, just that the h1 is followed by a body tag. I have no idea how to do this, except that my research into using regex didn't pan out. I can't be the first person to check for this or something like this. Is something like this barking up the wrong tree:

```
<xsl:when test=following-sibling::$elementValue[1][self::body]>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:message>ERROR: Encountered an head 1 paragraph that was not followed by a body tag.</xsl:message>
    <xsl:call-template name="revealDocPosition"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:when>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you please post the XML part?

Comment: here's a snippet of what I'd be searching for, head1 followed by body:

    <title role="head1">Third-Party Notices and/or Licenses</title><para role="body">Required notices for open source software products or components used by Cloud are identified in the following table along with the applicable licensing information.</para>

Comment: will `<xsl:when test="w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='head1'][following-sibling::*[1][self::body]]">` suffice?

Comment: Thanks! It look like this code checks to see if head1 is followed by body. Is there a way to test if head1 is NOT followed by body?